# laravel no result from my query

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner in Laravel

```
public function allorders($param1){
    $customerss=Customer::where('mobile_number',$param1)->first();
    $customer_id1=$customerss->id;
    $orderss= Order::where('customer_id',$customer_id1);

    return view('admin.allorders')->with('orderss', $orderss);
}
```

and i have the view `admin.allorders`

```
@foreach ($orderss as $tag)
    <span class="label label-primary">{{  $tag['customer_id']}}</span>
@endforeach
```

I'm sure the `$orderss` is having data but it's not shown in the view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `get()` to execute the query:

```
$orderss = Order::where('customer_id', $customer_id1)->get();
```

Also, you could use relationships instead of this:

```
$customerss=Customer::where('mobile_number',$param1)->first();       
$customer_id1=$customerss->id;
$orderss= Order::where('customer_id',$customer_id1);
```

You could do the same with just one query:

```
$orderss = Order::whereHas('customer', function($q) use($param1) {
    $q->where('mobile_number', $param1);
})->get();
```

To make it work, define this relationship in the `Order` model:

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
}
```

Comment: I didn't even spot that :|